# Dell Studio 15 Broadcom wireless drivers not working in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, linux-mint, broadcom

I installed Linux Mint 12 on my Dell Studio 15 and everything worked perfectly up until I tried updating the STA Driver for the Broadcom (BCM4312) wireless controller.

I've tried these bash commands in order and I still don't have wireless.

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

I've also tried uninstalling everything with synaptic package manager including `broadcom-sta-common` and `broadcom-sta-source`, then restarting and running the above commands which didn't work either.

What's the best way to do this on a Dell Studio 15?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:** I found this thread in linuxmint forums. This solution is meant for LMDE but I can confirm it works with KDE as well. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/218

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something similar using Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron using Synaptic Package Manager, however I had to browse inside of the GUI of SPM to get it done.

I had to plug into an ethernet jack to get internet access.  I also updated the OS via an update manager and restarted...

When I opened up SPM, I searched for broadcom drivers, and doing so I could only get results for searching "bcm".  A few things would show up including bcd-kernel (something similar to this) and also something along the lines of firmware installer & fwcutter.

I uninstalled and reinstalled these (sometimes it appeared they were installed, for some reason) then upon restarting the system, my wireless card could access networks.

I hope you figure it out.  This was really frustrating for me.